# fadeIn jquery en el llamando de un function

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

el problema es que necesito aplica fadeIn en un function

```
success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        viewUser();
    }
```

cuando ocurre el success el `viewUser();` me actualizara la tabla de usuario, el problema es que quisiera aplicar el efecto fadeIN dejquery

Comment: Que es exactamente que te devuelve `viewUser();`? o quizas muestres tambien esa funcion

Comment: el viewUser(); me devuelve el while de una consulta

Answer (score 0):

Tu código quedaría algo así:

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    viewUser();
    $( "#MiTabla" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
        // Más codigo OPCIONAL para cuando termine el fadeIN...
     });
}
```